# Where to place gvimrc and vimrc?

Tags: linux, vim, fedora

Ok, I have just installed Fedora but I traditionally am a Mac user. Well I would like to get vim setup in fedora similarly as to how I have it setup in OSX. My questions is where should I place my gvimrc and vimrc files? In /usr/share/vim? (I believe that's the path). Plugins as well. Can I install pathogen in vim/autoloads and place plugins in vim/bundles? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: /usr/share/vim is for all users and is really under the OS vendor's control not yours or even your administrator- definitely this is true in OSX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditionally your personal `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` go in your home directory (`~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvimrc`).  According to [this site](http://tammersaleh.com/posts/the-modern-vim-config-with-pathogen) all of your pathogen plugins go in `~/.vim/bundle`.